# How to Identify nested Group in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have one object source which is IEnumerable<T> where T can be either some Class or IGrouping or nested IGrouping.

How can i identify whether it is a nested Group or single group or not Grouped?

Comment: I've got an awnser... but it is so damn ugly that I do not want to post it :(

Comment: Thats OK jan, Please share the answer

Comment: Posted it... I hope it helps you

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why do you want to do that? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Svick, I have one function when IEnumerable is an argument and i need to display its contents to View, Best part here is source can be grouped, ordered etc. Only thing which makes high effect is groupd data where i need to display keys and Data, hence I need to Identify whether data is grouped or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty approach, but not very nice because of mighty `string` equalizations.

```
public bool isOrHasGrouping<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    return
        typeof(T).Name.Contains("IGrouping") 
            ? true
        : (typeof(T).ContainsGenericParameters 
            ? typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments
                    .Any(item => item.Name.Contains("IGrouping")) 
            : false);
 }
```

Comment: The name 'IGrouping' will probably not change in the future, so it is not that dirty, but plain 'Contains' may return false positives. It's better to use a more verbose condition like `type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(IGrouping<>)`. But, if you really don't care about false positives, then `type.FullName.Contains("IGrouping")` would probably be sufficient ;)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me. Thanks Jan. Below is the function I took from your answer:

```
public static bool HasInnerGrouping<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    return typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments.Any(item => item.Name.Contains("IGrouping"));
}
```